# Use relative path in gradle.properties and local.properties - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use relative path in gradle properties file in android studio to use it in different locations.

I tried to just specify the directory in the project dir like this (gradle.properties):

```
org.gradle.java.home=jdk
```

And I did the same for the sdk in local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=sdk\\Sdk
```

When I execute only graldew, it works but when I'm trying to build the project with android studio it print:

```
Value 'jdk' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)
```

and it works only with the absolute path.

Comment: Have you got any solution?